# QTableWidget add item to selection

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget

I need to select several `QTableWidgetItem` objects. How can I do it in my program? Do I need to create my own model-view or can I do it in the simple `QTableWidget` object? And how?

Here is my code (not working):

```
int col = current->column();
int row = current->row();
int spancols = current->data(TableItem::SpannedCols).toUInt();
for (int ic = col; ic < spancols; ++ic)
{
    for (int ir = row; ir < rowCount() - 1; ++ir)
    {
        QModelIndex index = model()->index(ir, ic);
        selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
    }
}
```

Comment: in what way is it not working? Is only one selected and you want all? or is nothing selected?

Comment: @Hayt selection is not changed after this code.

Comment: @ExiD Check indices. All valid indices must be selected by your code, if exist. P.S.: you can optimize this code using `select` method overload with `QItemSelection` argument (may work surprisingly faster for big ranges).

Comment: @ExiD So, are the indices valid? Your code seems ok.

Comment: @Tomas yes. Seems ok. But selection does not change anyway.

Comment: @ExiD And how is your "do selection" code called? It's in a slot, in reaction to some signal?

Comment: As a side note, the `ir < rowCount() - 1` is probably incorrect. You probably don't want the `- 1` part.